# How to get scroll position from GridView?

Tags: android, gridview, scroll, position, scroll-offset

I am trying to build my own grid view functions - extending on the `GridView`.
The only thing I cannot solve is how to get the current scroll position of the `GridView`.

`getScrollY()` does always return 0, and the `onScrollListener`'s parameters are just a range of visible child views, not the actual scroll position.

This does not seem very difficult, but I just can't find a solution in the web.

Anybody here who have an idea?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I did not find any good solution, 
but this one is at least able to maintain the scroll position kind of pixel-perfectly:

```
int offset = (int)(<your vertical spacing in dp> * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density); 
int index = mGrid.getFirstVisiblePosition();
final View first = container.getChildAt(0);
if (null != first) {
    offset -= first.getTop();
}

// Destroy the position through rotation or whatever here!

mGrid.setSelection(index);
mGrid.scrollBy(0, offset);
```

By that you can not get an absolute scroll position, but a visible item + displacement pair.

NOTES:

- This is meant for API 8+.
- You can get  with mGrid.getVerticalSpacing() in API 16+.
- You can use mGrid.smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(index, offset) in API 11+ instead of the last two lines.

Hope that helps and gives you an idea.

Comment: container represent for which thing ?
please tell me

Comment: From my vague memory this is a copy / paste error and should be mGrid.

Comment: @SalmanAshraf the View which contains the elements, try mGrid otherwise

Comment: what does vertical spacing mean?

Comment: @chncwang as far as I remember this is the vertical spacing set to the GridView. So it is constant to your implementation.

Comment: @Christoph you sir, just saved my day! Since getScrollY always returns 0 and ScrollView didn't work for me, this one is a pretty neat solution. Thank you!

Comment: @Attila Molnár you are welcome - I am actually pretty surprised this is still useful and actually working 4.5 years and a dozen API versions later.

Answer (score 2):

On Gingerbread, GridView getScrollY() works in some situations, and in some doesn't. Here is an alternative based on the first answer. The row height and the number of columns have to be known (and all rows must have equal height):

```
public int getGridScrollY()
{
   int pos, itemY = 0;
   View view;

   pos = getFirstVisiblePosition();
   view = getChildAt(0);

   if(view != null)
      itemY = view.getTop();

   return YFromPos(pos) - itemY;
}

private int YFromPos(int pos)
{
   int row = pos / m_numColumns;

   if(pos - row * m_numColumns > 0)
      ++row;

   return row * m_rowHeight;
}
```

The first answer also gives a good clue on how to pixel-scroll a GridView. Here is a generalized solution, which will scroll a GridView equivalent to scrollTo(0, scrollY):

```
public void scrollGridToY(int scrollY)
{
   int row, off, oldOff, oldY, item;

   // calc old offset:
   oldY = getScrollY(); // getGridScrollY() will not work here
   row = oldY / m_rowHeight;
   oldOff = oldY - row * m_rowHeight;

   // calc new offset and item:
   row = scrollY / m_rowHeight;
   off = scrollY - row * m_rowHeight;
   item = row * m_numColumns;

   setSelection(item);
   scrollBy(0, off - oldOff);
}
```

The functions are implemented inside a subclassed GridView, but they can be easily recoded as external.

Comment: Fixed a bug in the first example.

Comment: The first code block above worked for me.  One adjustment I had to make was to add the grid's top padding [getPaddingTop()] to the computed value.  Thanks.